# Include months in oracle sql which are not listed

Tags: sql, oracle, sysdate

I have two tables which I'm looking for the number of records which have a foreign key in another table and grouping them by date.
For some months we don't have a record but I want to include those months with the value of 0 representing there wasn't any record for that month.

My SQL code is this :

```
SELECT count(*),
       TO_CHAR("TransactionDate",'MONTH')
FROM "Transaction"
WHERE "Type" IN
    (SELECT "TypeID"
     FROM "TYPE_OF_PRODUCT")
GROUP BY TO_CHAR("TransactionDate",'MONTH') ;
```

my current result is like this:

[image]

my current result is like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can generate all the months using `connect by` and left join you query with it:

```
select c.Mon,
    coalesce(t.cnt, 0) cnt
from (
    select to_char(add_months(sysdate, level), 'MONTH') Mon
    from dual connect by level <= 12
    ) c
left join (
    select count(*) cnt,
        TO_CHAR("TransactionDate", 'MONTH') Mon
    from "Transaction"
    where "Type" in (
            select "TypeID"
            from "TYPE_OF_PRODUCT"
            )
    group by TO_CHAR("TransactionDate", 'MONTH')
    ) t
    on c.Mon = t.Mon;
```

Also, as a side note, it's not a good practice to use `"` in identifiers. Use simple identifiers without double quotes.

Quoting from official site - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm

> Nonquoted identifiers cannot be Oracle Database reserved words. Quoted identifiers can be reserved words, although **this is not recommended**.

Comment: thank you ever so much, do we have a 12-record of months in Sysdate to query from ?

Comment: @andrew - We are deriving it using sysdate and `connect by` clause. Using connect by we'll generate 12 rows 1, 2.,3 .. 12. and add that many months to sysdate so that there is one date in each month and get the month name from all those 12 dates.